# How to show that cubic surface is not toric?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

I know how to show $\mathbb{P}^2$ blowing up at 0,1,2,3 points are toric, but I don't know how to show that blowing up at 4-8 points are not toric. can someone show that blowing up  $\mathbb{P}^2$ at 6 points (which is a cubic surface in  $\mathbb{P}^3$) is not toric to inspire me?

Answer (score 3):

The technique I'm imagining for showing this would be exactly the same for blowing up any $n>3$ points in $\mathbb{P}^2$. Here's a hint- I'd be glad to fill in the details a little if you so desire.

Hint: Look at the torus action on the blowup and compare it with the induced action on $\mathbb{P}^2$ via the blow-down map. What can you say? Are there any special points?

> Any automorphism of the blowup must send the $-1$ curves to $-1$ curves, which means the points in $\mathbb{P}^2$ that are the images of the $-1$ curves are fixed by the torus action. But the torus action fixes only 3 points of $\mathbb{P}^2$, so the number of exceptional curves in the blowup must be at most 3.

Comment: why the torus action fixes only 3 points of $\mathbb{P}^2$?

Comment: Here's a sketch:if a torus acts on a compact smooth manifold with finitely many fixed points, we have $|M^T|=\chi(M)$. $\chi(\mathbb{P}^2)=3$, so there you go. The proof of this is Lefschetz plus Mayer-Vietoris, if I remember correctly.